# How do you properly change a Fontello icon color without changing the background in CSS

Tags: html, css

Iv looked every where and most people are changing the backgrounds first :p is there any way I could change the color straight away without changing the background ? Thanks a lot, examples will be gladly appreciated :)))

Comment: Just use "color" didnt work ? Example if u you have <i clas="some-class"></i> than your Css should be i.some-class {color:Your-color;}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use "color" on your CSS. Sample :

```
<div>
<i class="icon-5x icon-search red"></i>
</div>

<div>
<i class="icon-5x icon-search green"></i>
</div>

<div>
<i class="icon-5x icon-search blue"></i>
</div>
```

Then for coloring it :

```
   div {
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

i.icon-5x {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}

i.green {color:green}
i.blue {color:blue}
i.yellow {color:yellow}
```

And finally :

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/dQ95h/1/)

Comment: Fiddle update so you have better understanding. Its just same like styling font.

Comment: Thanks a lot but will this work with an anchor tag? Sorry for sounding like such a noob, just really new to CSS