# Changing the colour of a glyphicon using CSS in the collapsed navbar component

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue on the following website: http://www.bestdiscointown.co.uk/

In order to view the issue please resize the website vertically so that the small collapsed navbar appears.

In the HTML that forms the small button component in the navbar on mobile viewports there are 3 `<span>` elements with the class `.icon-bar`. I am trying to style the hover and focus states with CSS in order so that the colour of the bar icons are blue.

```
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

Bootstrap sets a default colour value of:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I dont understand why my CSS rule isn't styling the focus and active states for the bar icons to be blue as shown below, it could possibly be a CSS specificity issue:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:focus {
  color: #5979CD;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Glyphicon same as font, use color value. Its work. This is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286724/how-do-you-properly-change-a-fontello-icon-color-without-changing-the-background/22286848#22286848

Comment: Example format please - what's the alternative to hex colour code?

Comment: .icon-bar {color:white Or #fff}

Comment: @Nucleo1985 if anything then rather `.icon-bar {color:white}` Or `.icon-bar {color:#fff}` - that's what you meant, right? ;)

Comment: .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar { backgroud: red} this is work to for change icon color

Comment: yes - but I'm trying to toggle the colours on focus and active states - I have attached an image of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the icon-bar elements to be a diiferent color, when you hover over the button, then the hover and focus rules should be on the button like so:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar
{
    background-color: #5979CD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in your styles.css (line 75) which is overriding bootstrap

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```